# What is the significance of super.onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        return true;

    }
    return false;
    //return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Why do i need to call the subclass's superclass implementation? Why can't I just return false if no action is required, as it is its default value anyway?

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29) suggest there is none, its just common practice